# How does Apollo Server serve up its schema?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I have a problem where my local dev the schema serves fine, but in the docker container I've build from a yarn 2 nested hierarchy it's not serving the schema, queries appear to work fine. I imagine this is something not being copied to the right place, or run from the right place but I'm not certain what it might be. No Errors that I can see in the logs, but we might not be catching them someplace. here's the request/response.

```
* Preparing request to http://localhost:4000/
* Current time is 2020-09-22T21:45:08.957Z
* Using libcurl/7.69.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1g zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.1.1 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.41.0
* Using default HTTP version
* Disable timeout
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 0 cookies
* Too old connection (2410 seconds), disconnect it
* Connection 47 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 47
*   Trying ::1:4000...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 4000 (#48)

> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:4000
> User-Agent: insomnia/2020.4.0
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1765

| {"query":"\n    query IntrospectionQuery {\n      __schema {\n        queryType { name }\n        mutationType { name }\n        subscriptionType { name }\n        types {\n          ...FullType\n        }\n        directives {\n          name\n          description\n          locations\n          args {\n            ...InputValue\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n\n    fragment FullType on __Type {\n      kind\n      name\n      description\n      fields(includeDeprecated: true) {\n        name\n        description\n        args {\n          ...InputValue\n        }\n        type {\n          ...TypeRef\n        }\n        isDeprecated\n        deprecationReason\n      }\n      inputFields {\n        ...InputValue\n      }\n      interfaces {\n        ...TypeRef\n      }\n      enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {\n        name\n        description\n        isDeprecated\n        deprecationReason\n      }\n      possibleTypes {\n        ...TypeRef\n      }\n    }\n\n    fragment InputValue on __InputValue {\n      name\n      description\n      type { ...TypeRef }\n      defaultValue\n    }\n\n    fragment TypeRef on __Type {\n      kind\n      name\n      ofType {\n        kind\n        name\n        ofType {\n          kind\n          name\n          ofType {\n            kind\n            name\n            ofType {\n              kind\n              name\n              ofType {\n                kind\n                name\n                ofType {\n                  kind\n                  name\n                  ofType {\n                    kind\n                    name\n                  }\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  ","operationName":"IntrospectionQuery"}

* upload completely sent off: 1765 out of 1765 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Vary: Origin
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 292
< ETag: W/"124-3pl/vJTvcH05VKWfKO4DAa/Thmw"
< Date: Tue, 22 Sep 2020 21:45:08 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive


 * Received 292 B chunk
 * Connection #48 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#options):

> `introspection`: If true, enables schema introspection by clients.
>
> The default value is true, unless the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production.

If your `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to `production`, you need to ensure you explicitly set `introspection` to `true`. This is also true for the `playground` option.

Comment: huh, I can open another question, but why would this be disabled in production mode? information exposure?

Comment: If you make the schema easily accessible, you hypothetically make it easier for malicious actors to find some vulnerability to expose. In reality, a determined attacker can surmise your schema anyway by inspecting traffic. In reality, you should have measures in place (authorization, complexity/depth limits, rate limiting etc.) that prevent abuse of your API in the first place. Disabling introspection is an empty gesture and should _not_ be considered standard practice.